# PERMISOS DE GEOLOCATION

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tengo una consulta encontre este codigo en internet el cual me funciona bien en mi pc pero al momento de abrirlo desde mi celular no me consulta si quiero darle permisos solo me tira el mensaje "User denied the request for Geolocation."

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}

function showError(error) {
    switch(error.code) {
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
            x.innerHTML = "User denied the request for Geolocation."
            break;
        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
            x.innerHTML = "Location information is unavailable."
            break;
        case error.TIMEOUT:
            x.innerHTML = "The request to get user location timed out."
            break;
        case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
            x.innerHTML = "An unknown error occurred."
            break;
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Prueba ingresar en una pestaña de incógnito (desde el cel). Si te funciona correctamente debes vaciar el cache del navegador.

Comment: Me sigue el mismo problema, intente con varios celulares por sierto tengo el mismo problema con la documentacion original de google maps https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geolocation